# DataGridComboboxColumn - Get cell value

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, cell, disabled-control

The task is the following: there is a DataGrid with ComboboxColumns. If user changes cell[2,3] and selected value!=0 then disable cell[3,2]. I wrote the following Handler:

```
    private void grAssessment_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
        int y = e.Row.GetIndex();           

        grAssessment.GetCell(x, y).IsEnabled = false;
        grAssessment.GetCell(x, y).Background = Brushes.LightGray;
    }
```

But it disables appropriate cell in anyway. How to add `selected value!=0` condition to this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it not so clear. Can you explain this again?

Comment: @llan, each dropdown has value {0,1,2,3,4,5}. if user edits cell[rowIndex, columnIndex] in a grid and selected value != 0 then cell[columnIndex, rowIndex] should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution

```
private void grAssessment_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
    int y = e.Row.GetIndex();
    DataGridCell cell = grAssessment.GetCell(y, x);
    if (((System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)(cell.Content)).Text != "")
    {
        grAssessment.GetCell(x, y).IsEnabled = false;
        grAssessment.GetCell(x, y).Background = Brushes.LightGray; 
    }
    else
    {
        grAssessment.GetCell(x, y).IsEnabled = true;
        grAssessment.GetCell(x, y).Background = Brushes.White; 
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this out:
 1. DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource (for current version only, use your own):

```
private ObservableCollection<ScoreData> _scores = new ObservableCollection<ScoreData>(

    new List<ScoreData> 
    {
        new ScoreData{Score = 1, ScoreVerbal = "the same"},
        new ScoreData{Score = 3, ScoreVerbal = "moderate superiority"},
        new ScoreData{Score = 5, ScoreVerbal = "strong superiority"},
        new ScoreData{Score = 7, ScoreVerbal = "the samvery strong superioritye"},
        new ScoreData{Score = 9, ScoreVerbal = "extremely superiority"},
    } );
```

2. Handler code (the handler defined on the data grid):

```
 private void SelectDataGrid_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, 
        DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var editingElement = e.EditingElement as Selector;
        if(editingElement == null) return;
        var selectedData = editingElement.SelectedItem as ScoreData;
        if(selectedData == null || selectedData.Score > 1) return;
        var dataGridCell = editingElement.GetVisualParentOfType<DataGridCell>();
        if(dataGridCell == null) return;
        dataGridCell.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

3. GetVisualParentOfType code (as part of extension class):

```
public static class VisualTreeExtensions
{
     public static T GetVisualParentOfType<T>(this DependencyObject child)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (child is T) 
            return child as T;
        var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parentObject == null) return null;
        var parent = parentObject as T;
        return parent ?? GetVisualParentOfType<T>(parentObject);
    }

    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

regards,

Comment: @llan, unfortunately it doesn't work in the way I described